# Leave space on right with angular ng-grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I'm trying to add columns to a `ng-grid` but facing problem with the last column. Even I set the width of the last column, the component enlarge it to the end of the grid. So when I have more rows, a vertical scroll bar as well as an unnecessary  horizontal scroll bar is added.
How can I avoid this?

Comment: Please post your code what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem upgrading to ui-grid. with the new version I have a better control of everything